# WPF container window/child window. Possible?

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application, with a main window that contains a menu. Each menu item creates a corresponding pop up window.

Is there any way I can contain these windows within the main window i.e. they always remain within the main parent window's borders, and when the parent window is minimised, then these windows are minimised too, with only the parent window appearing in the task bar.

edit: I could obviously use user controls, but the project specification calls for the ability to open multiple windows side by side.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a [MDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface) implementation using WPF?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
newWindow.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

where `newWindow` is the name of the pop up window. Or

```
// Create a window and make this window its owner
Window ownedWindow = new Window();
ownedWindow.Owner = this;
ownedWindow.Show();
```

Find more about [Window.Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi Saagar, Thank you for that. That solves half my problem i.e. when I minimise my main window, the other windows minimise with only the container window visible in the task bar. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

why do you use a window if it should not be one.

Use a page or user control instead. Just change the base class of the "childwindow" to something that fits your needs.

Comment: The project requirements call for the ability to open multiple windows side by side.

Comment: Split the Window as a Simple "Host" which can contain any UserControl and implement the whole UI as UserControls, now you can display the UserControls side by side in one Window, or every UserControl in its own window

Comment: I have done that, but that wasn't my issue. Saagar has given me an excellent solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have misunderstood your question, As Saagar did answer it you should mark it as answer.